# ORDER BY id DESC in combination with WHERE id < ... won't use index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very large MySQL table (half a billion rows), something like a "log file", in which I read data as a stream of chunks from "current" into "past". The mechanics is like the following: The first query fetches e.g. the most recent 10 entries, and the user can choose to load "more from past", which means loading the 10 most recent entries which are older than the oldest one already loaded. Instead of time, rows are identified by ids. So the query has a `WHERE id < [the id of the oldest entry already loaded]` as well as `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10` in order to load the "next 10" rows.

The `WHERE` together with the `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10` work fine if I use an index over `(id)` column only.

However, my scenario is a bit more complicated than that. The huge table is actually a combination of several log files. So the `WHERE` clause also filters out which kind of log file to display. The log files are organized in a two level hierarchy. Let's call the columns which specify the log file `x` and `y`. Both columns are of type `varchar(32)` collate `ascii_general_ci`, and I have an index `(x, y, id)` which uses them both in full text. (I'm thinking about simplifying this by using numerical identificators for the log file (and not using two levels of hierarchy for them), however, the following is very strange.)

So my query contains the following clause:

```
WHERE x = ... AND y = ... AND id < [the id of the oldest entry already loaded]
```

together with the beforementioned

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

The index `(x, y, id)` is very nicely being used by MySQL if I do NOT order descendingly but ascendingly instead. However, when sorting descendingly, it will not be used.

1. Original query **(slow)**

   `SELECT * FROM syncLog WHERE x = '' AND y = '' AND id < 438353696 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

   ```
   select_type?  table?   partitions?  type?  possible_keys?  key?    key_len?  ref?         rows?     Extra?
   SIMPLE        syncLog  NULL         ref    PRIMARY,x_y_id  x_y_id  68        const,const  37040991  Using where
   ```
2. Sorting ascendingly **(fast)**

   `SELECT * FROM syncLog WHERE x = '' AND y = '' AND id < 438353696 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10`

   ```
   select_type?  table?   partitions?  type?  possible_keys?  key?    key_len?  ref?         rows?     Extra?
   SIMPLE        syncLog  NULL         ref    PRIMARY,x_y_id  x_y_id  68        const,const  37041163  Using index condition; Using where
   ```
3. Without x,y **(fast)**

   `SELECT * FROM syncLog WHERE id < 438353696 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

   ```
   select_type?  table?   partitions?  type?  possible_keys?  key?    key_len?  ref?         rows?     Extra?
   SIMPLE        syncLog  NULL         range  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 8         NULL         37041281  Using where
   ```

I also tried `FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (x_y_id)`, but it doesn't change anything (compared to 1.).

I also tried to include `x` and `y` in `ORDER BY`. I guessed, for MySQL to make use of the index for that, both `x` and `y` need also being included descendingly, although it doesn't make much sense here (since the result only contains same values for `x` and `y` anyways). `ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC, id DESC` But it didn't change anything either.

Why is the index not being used when searching for the rows with the 10 largest ids? How can this be fixed?

Interestingly, when forcing MySQL to use the primary index for this query (as in 1. but with `FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)`), the query is fast. However, this can be a problem as soon as the individual log files become very sparse, since they share one id space, resulting in large portions of the table to be scanned for finding 10 rows which have the correct `x` and `y`.

This setup uses a pretty outdated MySQL version: 5.6.25

Comment: You are using the rough labels "slow" and "fast," but can you quantify the running times here?  How much slower is the first version than the second two?

Comment: The "fast" one is in the range of tens of ms, the slow one depends on how far in the past I go. It becomes slower when the parameter I put in `WHERE id < ...` becomes lower (seconds, minutes, then hours...). So I guess that MySQL scans backwards from the most recent one until it finds 10 matching rows. So I think the "fast" one is `O(1)` and the "slow" one is `O(delta_id)` where `delta_id` is `MAX(id)` minus the one I put in `WHERE id < ...`.

Comment: For this, you will have to understand how data is stored in a BTREE+ structure. General idea is that when MySQL is using `x_y_id` index, it will either scan in ascending order of `id` or descending order of `id`. Now, depending on the type of range scan on id, that is, `>` or `<`, it will decide ascending / descending scan. If it goes for ascending scan, and in your order by clause, you specify descending sort `order by id desc`. These are two contrasting scenarios, and it will then to have to resort to filesort for last `order by` specification.

Comment: It is well explained here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

In MySQL 8+,  you can define indexes with ASC / DESC specification and can use them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It helps. However, in my head it makes totally sense to split the process in two scans: one to find the max value (`<`), then turn around to scan until I have enough rows (ORDER DESC in combination with LIMIT). But it seems MySQL doesn't do that...

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya But my understanding is that MySQL generally has the ability to use an ASC index backwards, or vice-versa for a DESC index (except in a few special cases).

Comment: Also, I wonder why it (at least seems that) works exactly like I just described when using the primary index... This is strange to me.

Comment: @leemes Well if you have a query which can use the primary key clustered index, it would completely cover the entire select clause.  So, MySQL would be more likely to use this index over a non clustered one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is what I am saying but there is an additional range condition on `id` as well. So, to satisfy the range condition first, MySQL will decide either to go ascending scan or descending scan. Let's say it goes for ascending scan; but now you are asking to sort again but descending..that wont happen without a filesort

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Right, so in that case MySQL probably just decides to not even bother using the index.

Comment: @leemes I think MySQL has optimizer trace profiling available in 5.6 Can you check this and try to execute it and give the output of the same to the question. Refer http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/optimizer-trace.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I will give this a try, but I think I have only time in a couple of hours. I want to understand why the index is rejected, and I guess the Optimizer trace can help me with that. (See also comments to my own answer.) Thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best guess as to what is happening.  Here is your query again, just for easy reference:

```
SELECT *
FROM syncLog
WHERE x = '' AND y = '' AND id < 438353696
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10
```

In the case of an ascending sort, MySQL would only have to do a single index scan on `id`, starting from the left (lowest) side.  Note that this kills two birds with one stone, because the scan satisfies both the `WHERE` restriction `id < 438353696` *and* the sorting requirement in the `ORDER BY` clause.

However, in the descending sort version, it is not the same thing:

```
SELECT *
FROM syncLog
WHERE x = '' AND y = '' AND id < 438353696
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

In this case, MySQL might choose to not scan the index to satisfy the `WHERE` criterion on `id`.  The reason is that it would not know (or even be able to find) the position in the index to the left of which `id < 438353696` would be true.  So, it chooses to just scan the table.  That being done, it then proceeds to just manually sort the result set, leading to the degrading performance you are seeing.

Comment: Actually indexes are stored in ascending order (unless you specify explicitly in MySQL 8). When we are in a Composite index situation, we don't have any option but to go in ascending order only especially for later columns (except first column in the key)

Comment: Only when the index is a single column or you are using the first column of a composite key, then you can scan either backwards or forwards accordingly.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Ahaa, that is interesting. I thought I am fine when sorting the composed columns all in the same way. In my head, the columns are "simply concatenated" (although for sure this is not the case). Then, I thought `x DESC, y DESC, id DESC` scans the whole index backwards and I'm fine. So this is not the case, as it seems... I could verify if I drop the WHERE, right?

Comment: @leemes worth a try. I don't have big hopes though that optimizer would be intelligent enough for this

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. Your hints made me understand a lot better what is happening behind the scenes.

However, the solution was too simple: I should not have said `FORCE INDEX FOR OREDER BY` and neither just `USE INDEX`. The solution is to `FORCE INDEX`.

In detail:

Before, I tried:

- Simply using an index hint without forcing it **(slow)**:

  `SELECT * FROM syncLog USE INDEX (x_y_id) WHERE x = '' AND y = '' AND id < 438459282 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

  ```
  select_type?  table?   partitions?  type?  possible_keys?  key?    key_len?  ref?         rows?     Extra?
  SIMPLE        syncLog  NULL         ref    x_y_id          x_y_id  68        const,const  37042925  Using where
  ```
- Forcing the index, however in a silly rush I told MySQL to force it for ordering! **(slow)**

  `SELECT * FROM syncLog FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (x_y_id) WHERE x = '' AND y = '' AND id < 438459282 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

  ```
  select_type?  table?   partitions?  type?  possible_keys?  key?    key_len?  ref?         rows?     Extra?
  SIMPLE        syncLog  NULL         ref    PRIMARY,x_y_id  x_y_id  68        const,const  37042973  Using where
  ```

The solution is:

- Forcing the index, but not telling MySQL for what. **(fast)**

  `SELECT * FROM syncLog FORCE INDEX (x_y_id) WHERE x = '' AND y = '' AND id < 438459282 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

  ```
  select_type?  table?   partitions?  type?  possible_keys?  key?    key_len?  ref?  rows?     Extra?
  SIMPLE        syncLog  NULL         range  x_y_id          x_y_id  76        NULL  37042943  Using index condition
  ```

Now have a look at `key_len`. MySQL didn't use the `id` part of the index before. Now it is using it.

Comment: `The solution is to FORCE INDEX` ... note that the majority of the time you should _not_ force an index which the optimizer doesn't want to use.  The reason for this is simple: the optimizer is usually smarter than you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I totally hear you. I don't know why the optimizer doesn't recognize that the index can (and should) be used in this case. Do you know of a way to inspect this?

Comment: Well here's the thing: the index might be faster for this particular query.  But, this doesn't guarantee it would work, for example, as your underlying data changes or as you make other changes to the query.  Take the optimizer's rejection of the index as  a friendly suggestion that it might not help.  But, sometimes it can be wrong.